# Error When Filtering Legacy Enum Fields in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, ruby-on-rails-7

When applying the filters on the fields populated using the legacy enum, rails_admin breaks throwing the undefined method [] for nil:NilClass while rendering the content on the page.

We use rails_admin in a large Rails project and started facing this issue after upgrading rails_admin from 2 to 3 and the Rails version from 6 to 7. I have created a dummy application replicating the setup we have with all the configuration, first we had assumed that the problem lies within the configuration of our company's code but the issue replicated itself within the new application as well, link to the repo, this was a fresh install of Rails 7.1 along with rails_admin.

Description
When applying the filters on the fields populated using the legacy enum, rails_admin breaks throwing the undefined method [] for nil:NilClass while rendering the content on the page.

We use rails_admin in a large Rails project and started facing this issue after upgrading rails_admin from 2 to 3 and the Rails version from 6 to 7. I have created a dummy application replicating the setup we have with all the configuration, first we had assumed that the problem lies within the configuration of our company's code but the issue replicated itself within the new application as well, link to the repo, this was a fresh install of Rails 7.1 along with rails_admin.

Reproduction Steps
Apply a filter on any of the fields utilizing the legacy enum.

Expected Behavior
Expect the page to render properly with either the resulting set or no records found.

Additional context

rails version: 7.1
ruby version: 2.7.6
rails_admin version: 3.1.2
rails_admin npm package version: NA (Using sprockets)
Github Link to dummy application: https://github.com/deepakisrani/test_app
Reproduction Steps
Apply a filter on any of the fields utilizing the legacy enum.

Expected Behavior
Expect the page to render properly with either the resulting set or no records found.

Comment: Your question has duplicated text, please clean it up.